# Codelite error while loading shared libraries but I can compile it

Tags: c++, codelite

I meet problems when using Codelite 11. My program need the libraries "libHYPRE-2.11.2.so". I added the path in the "linker" option (see the attached).[set in the linker option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGXs7.jpg). So, I can complie it with no problem. But if I try to run it by clicking "build->run" (in codelite), the errors comes (see the attached)  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcrVz.jpg), it says it cannot find the libraries (noted it, I can run it just writting "./REEF3D"  the terminal window of linux).

So, My problem seems to find how to add the library path in codelite when I want to run it. So anyone who can help?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's now working for you since it's been a couple of months and you've likely rebooted (which will also fix the problem).  To fix the problem without rebooting, run the command "sudo ldconfig -v".  This will make the system aware of any new libraries that you've added and then your code should run (or at least it will be able to find the library).